# Android Studio - ARCore - E/DynamiteClient: Failed to load native library [packageName=com.google.ar.core,libraryName=arcore_c] from remote package:

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

I'm trying to follow an [Android ARCore tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntEBeB37p5Q&list=PLsOU6EOcj51cEDYpCLK_bzo4qtjOwDWfW&index=18) however I keep on getting this error when I try to start the app:

```
E/DynamiteClient: Failed to load native library [packageName=com.google.ar.core,libraryName=arcore_c] from remote package:

    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.google.ar.core-dmlqkWErgZyoM0RLfsTjSw==/lib/arm/libarcore_c.so" has unexpected e_machine: 40 (EM_ARM)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
        at com.google.vr.dynamite.NativeLibraryLoader.a(PG:30)
        at com.google.vr.dynamite.NativeLibraryLoader.initializeAndLoadNativeLibrary(PG:14)
        at evx.a(PG:7)
        at xo.onTransact(PG:5)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:667)
        at com.google.a.a.b.transactAndReadException(BaseProxy.java:10)
        at com.google.vr.dynamite.client.b.initializeAndLoadNativeLibrary(INativeLibraryLoader.java:5)
        at com.google.vr.dynamite.client.DynamiteClient.loadNativeRemoteLibrary(DynamiteClient.java:26)
        at com.google.ar.core.Session.nativeCreateSessionAndWrapperWithFeatures(Native Method)
        at com.google.ar.core.Session.<init>(Session.java:14)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.createSessionWithFeatures(BaseArFragment.java:419)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.createSession(BaseArFragment.java:405)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.initializeSession(BaseArFragment.java:379)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.onResume(BaseArFragment.java:338)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2649)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:922)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:268)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:479)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:468)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3776)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3816)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
I/third_party/arcore/java/com/google/vr/dynamite/client/native/dynamite_client.cc: Dynamite::LoadNativeRemoteLibrary handle=0
E/third_party/arcore/ar/core/android/sdk/session_create.cc: Dynamite failed to load remote library
    LoadSymbolsDynamite returning AR_ERROR_FATAL.
    LoadSymbols returning status.
E/StandardArFragment: Error: Failed to create AR session
    com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableException
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.initializeSession(BaseArFragment.java:391)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.onResume(BaseArFragment.java:338)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2649)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:922)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:268)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:479)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:468)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7317)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3776)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3816)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: com.google.ar.core.exceptions.FatalException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at com.google.ar.core.Session.throwExceptionFromArStatus(Session.java:143)
        at com.google.ar.core.Session.nativeCreateSessionAndWrapperWithFeatures(Native Method)
        at com.google.ar.core.Session.<init>(Session.java:14)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.createSessionWithFeatures(BaseArFragment.java:419)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.createSession(BaseArFragment.java:405)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.initializeSession(BaseArFragment.java:379)
        at com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment.onResume(BaseArFragment.java:338) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2649) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:922) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2625) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:268) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:479) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:468) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7317) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3776) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3816) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I'm not too sure why I'm getting this error. I've rechecked my code and it has everything the tutorial has. I've done a fair amount of search for documentation on the error and have not found any answers on how to resolve it.

here is my code:

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.arcoretestjava">

    <!-- "AR Required" apps must declare minSdkVersion >= 24. -->
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="29"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.ar" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="required"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**build.gradle(app)**

```
    implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.15.0'
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.16.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks from there error that you are running the app on an Intel rather than an ARM device - the different hardware's often require different library files.

If you are running the app in an emulator then the ARCore instructions provide information on setting up x86 support for the emulator (https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/emulator):

> Get Android Studio and SDK tools for ARCore
>
> Install Android Studio 3.1 or later.
>
> In Android Studio, go to Preferences > Appearance and Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK.
>
> Select the SDK Platforms tab and check Show Package Details.
>
> Under Android 8.1 (Oreo), select:
>
> **Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image API Level 27, version 4 or later.**
>
> Select the SDK Tools tab and add Android Emulator 27.2.9 or later.
>
> Click OK to install the selected pacakges and tools.
>
> Click OK again to confirm changes.
>
> Accept the license agreement for the Component Installer.
>
> Click Finish.

Look at the Note on needing x86 API's if your app includes NDK components also, at the same link above, as a check, but I don't think this applies to your case at the moment.

If for some reason you need to run on x86b and there are no x86 versions of some binaries you need, there is a library which facilitates this called libhoundi. There is a good overview of it here: https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/11/21/libhoudini-what-it-means-for-developers.html

Again, I don't think this applies in your case but it may be useful to know as background.

Comment: That ended up helping. I was missing the part where I had to drag over the APKs to the emulator. I also went up to using the following and the error went away. `Pixel 2 API 29 - Q10.0 x86`